# Swift delegate protocol not calling

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I'm a beginner in Swift. I'm trying to use delegate and protocol to send the data backward from a child view to the root view (in navigation controller)

Here is my code:

```
//FilterViewController.swift:

protocol FilterDelegate: class {
    func finishFilter(query: String);
}

class FilterViewController:BaseViewController,....{
    ....
    weak var delegate : FilterDelegate?

    @IBAction func acceptTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var querystring = ""
        var conditions: [String] = []
        //some logic works with conditions
        querystring = conditions.joined(separator: "&")
        self.delegate?.finishFilter(query: querystring)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is where I call the delegate from Filter

```
//HouseListController.swift

class HouseListController: BaseViewController,..{
    var filterController = FilterViewController()

    //Here is where I push the FilterViewController
    @IBAction func filterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.currentMode = .filter
        self.tracking.previousMode = .filter
        self.filterController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterView") as! FilterViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.filterController, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.filterController.delegate = self
    }
}   

extension HouseListController : FilterDelegate {
    func finishFilter(query: String) {
        switch self.currentMode{
        case .normal:
            _ = self.filterHouse(querystring: query , offset: 0, limit: self.tracking.limit).done{ dataHouses in
                self.houses.filter = dataHouses
                self.houses.defaultHouses = dataHouses
                }.done{ _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
            }
        case .search:
            _ = self.filterHouse(searchKey: self.tracking.search.searchKey, querystring: query, offset: 0, limit: self.tracking.limit).done{ dataHouses in
                self.houses.filter = dataHouses
                self.houses.defaultHouses = dataHouses
                }.done{ _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
            }
        default:
            _ = self.filterHouse(querystring: query , offset: 0, limit: self.tracking.limit).done{ dataHouses in
                self.houses.filter = dataHouses
                self.houses.defaultHouses = dataHouses
                }.done{ _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
            }
        }
        self.currentMode = .filter
    }
}
```

The delegate is not calling to my finishFilter function. Instead, when I pop the view in FilterController, it go straight to viewWillAppear in HouseListController and just stuck there without any calling to the delegate.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show in `filterTapped` is the problem. You create a new instance of `FilterViewController` from the storyboard but you never set that instance's `delegate` property.

I would get rid of your `filterController` property. Get rid of the line in `viewDidLoad` that sets its `delegate`. You never used that code so you have no need for it.

Then update `filterTapped`:

```
@IBAction func filterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.currentMode = .filter
    self.tracking.previousMode = .filter
    let filterController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterView") as! FilterViewController // Update this line
    filterController.delegate = self // Add this line
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.filterController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, so i must set the delegate to the instance which i use to push in the navigation controller. I understand it now, thank you very much for your reply, sir! It's working perfect now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data backward use closure. Lets say you have 2 viewcontrollers A & B, and you want data from B to A, declare closure in B viewcontroller.

```
class B_ViewController: UIViewController{
   var closureData: ((NSMutableArray) -> Void) = { arg in }

    @IBAction func onBtnDoneClick(_ sender: Any) {
        self.closureData(self.selectedClosureArray)
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Now in view controller A call closure declare in view controller B.
Here `A_VC_array` is `NSMutableArray`, and `bVC` is object of Viewcontroller B.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.bVC.closureData  = { (selectedClosureData:NSMutableArray) -> Void in
        self.A_VC_array = selectedClosureData
    }
}
```